# How to Avoid "Used by another process" When using File.Copy in C#

Tags: c#, process, copy

I am trying to Copy File from path to another using the following code:

```
 File.Copy(oldPath, newPath);.
```

newPath represent Path and filename like `C:\txt.txt`

oldPath represent path and filename like `d:\d.txt`

I get the following Exception:

> C:\txt.txt Used From another Process

Why this issue showing?

Comment: What exception is thrown, and what do you have in oldPath and newPath when the exception is thrown?

Comment: "Used by another process" - Sound like you need a file lock?

Comment: yes, Thanks @ChristoferEliasson ..Could you please vote my question up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the reason because one of the programs from Windows is using the file you are trying to copy -- in my case the file was used by Visual Studio cs was in debug file ...

Answer (score 1):

There are eight potential exceptions that could happen: UnauthorizedAccessException, ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException, PathTooLongException, DirectoryNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, IOException or NotSupportedException (consult MSDN documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx to find details of these exceptions).

You indicated, that the file is locked by the process that created it. That should solve your problem:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create("c:\\michal.txt")) 
{ 
}

File.Copy("c:\\michal.txt", "c:\\michal_new.txt");

File.Delete("c:\\michal.txt");
File.Delete("c:\\michal_new.txt");
```

Comment: Unhandled exception has occureed the process can not access the file "C:\...\n.jpg' because it is being Used By another Process

Comment: Visual Studio lock my File because i used it in the same process to add file in newpath before trying to delete or copy it .. so Maybe Myquestion how to close file Created by file.Copy(oldpath,newpath); statment ?

Comment: thanks Michal but the Compiler thrown Exception  Unhandled exception has occureed the process can not access the file **"c:\\michal_new.txt"**  because it is being Used By another Process